# Health endpoints only says "status: up" and does not show up sensitive information

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, endpoint, health-monitoring

I set up a spring booth with ResourceServerConfigurerAdapeer. I want to show up the sensitive data of my health end point but it only shows

{status: UP}

spring.profiles.active: oauth 
endpoints.health.sensitive: false

This is what I read from Spring documentation.

Information returned by HealthIndicators is often somewhat sensitive in nature. For example, you probably don’t want to publish details of your database server to the world. For this reason, by default, only the health status is exposed over an unauthenticated HTTP connection. If you are happy for complete health information to always be exposed you can set endpoints.health.sensitive to false.

How do we show other information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem that I was able to fix by adding this line to the application.properties file.

```
# Disable security for actuator endpoints
management.security.enabled=false

# Disable sensitive filter for the health endpoint
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

This disables the security for all the actuator endpoints, so be aware of that. I recommend turning all the endpoints off and only enable those you need, e.g.

```
# Set all actuator endpoints disabled by default
endpoints.enabled=false
```

And to enable the `health` endpoint you can do the following,

```
endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

I hope this helps you.

See also this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5750) on the Github Repository for Spring Actuator.

Answer (score 1):

I Solve that case when add some properties :

```
## HEALTH
endpoints.health.enabled.sensitive=false

management.health.db.enabled=true

management.health.defaults.enabled=true

management.health.diskspace.enabled=true

management.security.enabled=false

endpoints.enabled=false

endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

And Show Json {"status":"", "diskSpace":{}, "db":""}. Hope can help you.